# Ethernet connection issue after installing xampp on ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: ethernet, xampp

I had installed Ubuntu server 16.04 then I installed Xampp and then the connection to the internet doesn't work properly. I don't know what the problem is exactly.

When I use the same broadband connection on the other PC it works.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  I've edited your question to improve clarity.  If my edits deviate from your original intent, feel free to re-edit or rollback.

Comment: I saw your edit and it's fine but i really need an answer

Comment: Sohype, have you tried uninstalling xaamp?

Comment: no i didn't try that

Comment: Okay, then try running `sudo apt purge xaamp`.